# Selected rows not displaying when i display rows in Decrement order

Tags: php

[image]

**Background** :

when a user selects one of the option [ example : Undelivered ] in the drop down menu, then i am displaying only the rows which have that value [ example : Undelivered ]

[image]

```
<tr><th>
<select id="my_select" onchange="send_option();">
<option value="all">Status</option>

<?php

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT in_transit FROM do_order";
$result = mysqli_query ($mysqli, $query);
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
  echo "<option value='" . $row['in_transit'] . "'>" . $row['in_transit'] . "</option>";
?>              
</select>  
</th></tr>

<?php
$theBigQuery = "SELECT * FROM do_order WHERE 1";

        if (isset($_POST['my_option']) && $_POST['my_option'] != "")
        {
            if($_POST['my_option'] == "all")
            {

            } 
            else 
            {
                $theBigQuery .= " AND in_transit like '" . $_POST["my_option"] . "'";
            }
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>function changeOption(){document.getElementById('my_select').value='".$_POST['my_option']."';} changeOption();</script>";

        } 
$orderrecords = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($theBigQuery);

?>

<tr><td id="<?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"];?>">
<?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["in_transit"]; ?>  
</td></tr>

<form method="post" action"dashboard.php" style="display:none" id="my_form">
      <input type="text" id="my_option" name="my_option"/>      
</form>
```

**script**

```
function send_option () 
{
var sel = document.getElementById( "my_select" );
var txt = document.getElementById( "my_option" );
txt.value = sel.options[ sel.selectedIndex ].value;

var frm = document.getElementById( "my_form" );
frm.submit();
}
```

**Requirement** :

Now I want to display rows in **decrement** order , so in above code i changed below line . now rows are displaying in decrement order.

```
$theBigQuery = "SELECT * FROM do_order ORDER BY id DESC";
```

**Issue** :

but if i select any option in dropdown [ example : undelivered ] , its **not displaying** any rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using you edit, when you select an option, your query will become :

```
$theBigQuery = "SELECT * FROM do_order ORDER BY id DESC AND in_transit like 'Undelivered'";
```

This is a wrong `sql` query!!

So to fix this; leave the `$theBigQuery` as it was, and after the `if (isset( ..` test, before running the query, add the `ORDER BY` clause :

```
$theBigQuery = "SELECT * FROM do_order WHERE 1";

        if (isset($_POST['my_option']) && $_POST['my_option'] != "")
        {
            if($_POST['my_option'] == "all")
            {

            } 
            else 
            {
                $theBigQuery .= " AND in_transit like '" . $_POST["my_option"] . "'";
            }
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>function changeOption(){document.getElementById('my_select').value='".$_POST['my_option']."';} changeOption();</script>";

        } 
$theBigQuery .= " ORDER BY id DESC";
$orderrecords = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($theBigQuery);
```